# Div above other div

Tags: css, html

http://ipekevi.com/yeni/ in this page I want head div to above content div. I search here and find many solution but they don't work.
My part of css file about content and head div:

```
#content {
    z-index: 1;
}
#head {
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

I can not figure out. Please explain it.

Comment: I think you should show html code. To do this you mist decalre div in another div or declare one div after another.

Comment: `z-index` only works with `position: relative/absolute/fixed` which you don't have in `#content`

Comment: My first div is container. Please inspect our website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#content {
    z-index: 1;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#head {
    height: 140px;
    width:960px;
    z-index: 999;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

You have to define the position and size,

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Are you sure about both position: relative and position:absolute in the same rule?  (My CSS is a bit rusty).

Comment: Which position is for head?

Comment: Sorry they should both be absolute :)

Comment: When I change position of head div from relative to absolute, this time head menu fails.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle I can take a look at please?

Comment: I don't have a fiddle but you can inspect the site. Could you?

Comment: Could you please set up a fiddle? I can then edit it and give you the code straight away

Comment: I solved the problem with your clue. Really thanks. And I edit your code.